# PHP can't connect to the database after upgrading php and mysql, both to 5.5 on CentOS 5

Tags: php, mysql, centos5

I recently upgraded php from 5.2 to 5.5 on my server running CentOS 5.5.
Then I also upgraded mysql from 5.1 to 5.5.
Everething worked fine for a few days until now. Now any application installed on my server (such as trixbox, joomla, even phpMyAdmin) isn't able to connect to the database.
The problem is, I am receiving just general error messages such as "DB Error: connect failed" or "Cannot start session without errors..." (phpMyAdmin).

MySQL seems to be running and I can access and query it using CLI.
I've also tested socket functionality like this:

`mysql -u root -p --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

and it worked:

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor. (...) Your MySQL connection id is 2...

Should I downgrade mysql, php installation or both? If so, how?
Unfortunatelly, I didn't make any backups, except mysqldump, but database data seems fine.

Comment: be aware that PHP 5.5 is not formally released yet; it's still in beta. There shouldn't be a problem, but... well, beta is beta. Unless you're planning to use some of the new php 5.5 features, it would be best to wait for a formal release before installing it, particularly if you're only using third party apps such as joomla, which won't have been updated to use php 5.5. That said, it would help to get a better idea of the actual problem ; The errors coming from your apps aren't very helpful for this kind of thing; maybe you could write a simple test prog in PHP to help you debug the problem.

Comment: thanks, I tried script available here: [link](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/simple-php-mysql-connection-test-script-example-t5702.html) and the answer was: `The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`.

Comment: okay, that test script is out of date -- it uses the old `mysql_xxx()` functions, which are deprecated in php 5.5 and don't support features from newer mysql versions. that probably explains that much of the issue. you should try a test program that uses the PDO library instead. I would expect well-known programs like joomla and phpmyadmin not to have that specific problem; they are almost certainly using a more up-to-date database API -- at least as long as you have up-to-date versions of the apps (if not, you'll obviously need to update them as well as updating php and mysql).